# Designing algorithm to use available space in signup form in most efficient manner

Tags: c#, algorithms

The case is that I have a signup form for students where they can choose between different lessons in multiple rounds. Each lesson in each round has a defined available space. The total amount of space in each round is equal to the number of students which need to sign up. Students cannot pick the same lesson twice in different rounds. All available space in each round and each lesson should be used to allow all students to sign up.

See for example the following signup form with the defined rounds and spaces:

[image]

Imagine the following issue:

[image]

This results in the following spaces left:

[image]

In this case Lesson 3 hasn't been picked and has 1 space in each round left over. The solution I would like to see here is that student B is forced to pick lesson 3 so space is created for the third student to sign up. How do I solve this issue using some kind of algorithm?

I build the following sample code containing the issue. In this sample code the second sign up should have been rejected because it would disallow the third student to sign up respecting the limitation of not being able to sign up for the same lesson twice. The mandatory lesson (in this case lesson 3) should also be output to the console.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on what algorithm to use to solve this issue and maybe how to build the solution into the sample code? Maybe I am looking over something really simple. See the TODO defined in the code below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var form = new Form();
        form.AddLesson(LessonType.Lesson1, Round.Create(1, 1));
        form.AddLesson(LessonType.Lesson2, Round.Create(1, 1));
        form.AddLesson(LessonType.Lesson3, Round.Create(1, 1));

        //unique lesson in each round is necessary. Example below signs up for lesson 1 in round 1 and lesson 2 in round 2
        form.SignUp(LessonType.Lesson1, LessonType.Lesson2);
        form.SignUp(LessonType.Lesson2, LessonType.Lesson1);
        //In this situation there's only 2 spaces left for lesson 3. Which is an issue because you can't signup for the same lesson in multiple rounds.
        //So there's 2 spaces left over which could have been filled if the second person was forced to sign up for lesson 3

        if (!form.AssertAllRoundsFilled())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error there's still unused space in one or more rounds");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Form
{
    private Dictionary<LessonType, List<Round>> _context = new Dictionary<LessonType, List<Round>>();
    private int _userCount = 0;
    public bool ShouldBeAllowedToPickTheseRounds(LessonType[] lesson)
    {
        //Todo: Check if this person is allowed to pick this combination given the fact that we don't want any space leftover unused. 
        var isValid = true;

        if (!isValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Lesson x in round y is mandatory");
        }
        
        return isValid;
    }

    public bool SignUp(params LessonType[] lesson)
    {
        if (lesson.Distinct().Count() != lesson.Length) throw new Exception("Pick unique lesson in each round");

        if (!ShouldBeAllowedToPickTheseRounds(lesson))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Pick a different mandatory lesson combination");
        }
        
        for(var i=0; i< lesson.Length; i++)
        {
            var result = _context[lesson[i]][i].Signup();
            if (!result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Not enough space left for {lesson[i]} in round {i}");
                return false;
            }
        }
        _userCount++;
        Console.WriteLine($"Student {_userCount} signed up for: { string.Join(",", lesson)}");
        
        return true;
    }

    public void AddLesson(LessonType type, List<Round> rounds)
    {
        _context.Add(type, rounds);
    }

    public bool AssertAllRoundsFilled()
    {
        return !_context.Any(x => x.Value.Any(v => v.Space > 0));
    }

}   
public class Round
{
    public Round(int space)
    {
        Space = space;
    }
    public int Space { get; set; }

    public bool Signup()
    {
        if (Space < 0) return false;
        Space--;
        return true;
    }

    public static List<Round> Create(params int[] space)
    {
        return space.Select(x => new Round(x)).ToList();
    }
}

public enum LessonType
{
    Lesson1,
    Lesson2,
    Lesson3
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what your problem is? Because in the text you have described what the algorithm must be able to do. Now you have to translate that into code. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Darem Thank you, That is correct. I explained the issue, and created a sample project containing the issue and described how I would like this sample project to behave. I don't  expect someone to write the code for me but would like to be pointed into the right direction. I updated the question to be more specific

Comment: Possible duplicate on StackOverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177836/algorithm-for-creating-a-school-timetable

Comment: I do not believe that there is a standard algorithm. You just have to break the problem into smaller subproblems and solve them one by one. As an example, a student may not take a course twice. You can solve this by iterating over all students and checking if there is a duplicate entry in the list. The next subproblem is whether there are enough free seats. This can be checked in a similar way. I would first implement it as naive and simple as possible. And if you hit a performance bottle neck come back and ask about the percise problem.